# How to position images in a slider using js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a slideshow with 3 images of width 700px and I want to set the image 'left' position of each image from jquery, so that the images slide in, showing the current image and hiding the other images.

Here is the code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //calculating the no. of photos using each funct. Each func will detect the total imgs.
  $('.marquee_container .slide').each(function(index) {

    //setting the photowidth according to the container width
    var photoWidth = $('.marquee_container').width();

    //calculating the photoposition
    var photoPosition = index * photoWidth;

    //setting the left position of the photos
    $('.slide').css({
      'left': photoPosition
    });

    //caculating the width of the div depending on the photos
    $('.holder').css({
      'width': photoWidth + photoPosition
    });


  });

  //generating navigation links
  //calculating the no. of marquee_photos divs using the each func
  //appending html code inside the marquee_nav
  //the marquee_nav links will appear according to the number of marquee_photos divs, using the each function
  $('.slide').each(function(index) {
    $('.marquee_nav').append('<a href="#" class="marquee_nav_item"></a>');
  });
});
```

```css
.marquee_container {
  width: 700px;
  height: 350px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0px 0px 30px 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.holder {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 700px;
  height: 350px;
}
.slide {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
.marquee_photos {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.marquee_photos img {
  display: block;
}
.marquee_caption {
  width: 700px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 15px 0px 10px 0px;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 350px;
  left: 0px;
  background: url(images/template/marquee_caption.png) 0px 0px;
}
.marquee_caption_content {
  width: 410px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 25px;
}
.marquee_nav {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  right: 0;
}
.marquee_nav .marquee_nav_item {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: url(images/template/nav_buttons.png) no-repeat;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  width: 17px;
  height: 18px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 4px;
}
.marquee_nav .marquee_nav_item:hover {
  background: url(images/template/nav_buttons.png) no-repeat -25px 0;
}
.marquee_nav .marquee_nav_item:selected {
  background: url(images/template/nav_buttons.png) no-repeat -50px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="marquee_container">
  <div class="holder">
    <div class="slide">
      <img class="marquee_panel_photo" src="images/photos/london.jpg" alt="London" />
      <div class="marquee_caption">
        <div class="marquee_caption_content">
          <p>Content goes here</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img class="marquee_panel_photo" src="images/photos/milan.jpg" alt="milan" />
      <div class="marquee_caption">
        <div class="marquee_caption_content">
          <p>Content goes here</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img class="marquee_panel_photo" src="images/photos/staugustine.jpg" alt="staugustine" />
      <div class="marquee_caption">
        <div class="marquee_caption_content">
          <p>Content goes here</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="marquee_nav">
  </div>
</div>
```

I am able to add the width dynamically but all the images left position are equal to the last image i.e. left:1400

From js you can see that I have calculated each photo position using index but I am still not able to get the result.

Comment: Could you add a fiddle with images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR**

You are misusing [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) loop.

To access a value inside of `.each()` loop you have to use `value` argument.

```
$('.marquee_container .slide').each(function (index, value) {
    console.log($('.slide')); // All slides on the page.
    console.log($(value)); // A value for current iteration
});
```

**Detailed explanation**

Sizzle selector engine, used in jQuery returns a collection of matched elements, when you specify a class, and your DOM contains multiple elements with this class.

By calling `.each(callback)` on a jQuery Collection, you basically tell JavaScript to call `callback` function for every element in collection. The `callback` function accepts two arguments: `index, value`

Where `index` — current index in array or object, `value` — a single value from your collection.

By applying `$('.slide').css()`, you change CSS properties of all elements from collection. To assign a specific position for each element, you need to interact with every separate element by accessing `$(value)`.

**Fixing**

Please try this demo with your images:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //calculating the no. of photos using each funct. Each func will detect the total imgs.
  $('.marquee_container .slide').each(function(index, value) {

    //setting the photowidth according to the container width
    var photoWidth = $('.marquee_container').width();

    //calculating the photoposition
    var photoPosition = index * photoWidth;

    //setting the left position of the photos
    $(value).css({
      'left': photoPosition
    });

    //caculating the width of the div depending on the photos
    $('.holder').css({
      'width': photoWidth + photoPosition
    });


  });

  //generating navigation links
  //calculating the no. of marquee_photos divs using the each func
  //appending html code inside the marquee_nav
  //the marquee_nav links will appear according to the number of marquee_photos divs, using the each function
  $('.slide').each(function(index) {
    $('.marquee_nav').append('<a href="#" class="marquee_nav_item"></a>');
  });
});
```

```css
.marquee_container {
  width: 700px;
  height: 350px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0px 0px 30px 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.holder {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 700px;
  height: 350px;
}
.slide {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
.marquee_photos {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.marquee_photos img {
  display: block;
}
.marquee_caption {
  width: 700px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 15px 0px 10px 0px;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 350px;
  left: 0px;
  background: url(images/template/marquee_caption.png) 0px 0px;
}
.marquee_caption_content {
  width: 410px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 25px;
}
.marquee_nav {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  right: 0;
}
.marquee_nav .marquee_nav_item {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: url(images/template/nav_buttons.png) no-repeat;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  width: 17px;
  height: 18px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 4px;
}
.marquee_nav .marquee_nav_item:hover {
  background: url(images/template/nav_buttons.png) no-repeat -25px 0;
}
.marquee_nav .marquee_nav_item:selected {
  background: url(images/template/nav_buttons.png) no-repeat -50px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="marquee_container">
  <div class="holder">
    <div class="slide">
      <img class="marquee_panel_photo" src="images/photos/london.jpg" alt="London" />
      <div class="marquee_caption">
        <div class="marquee_caption_content">
          <p>Content goes here</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img class="marquee_panel_photo" src="images/photos/milan.jpg" alt="milan" />
      <div class="marquee_caption">
        <div class="marquee_caption_content">
          <p>Content goes here</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <img class="marquee_panel_photo" src="images/photos/staugustine.jpg" alt="staugustine" />
      <div class="marquee_caption">
        <div class="marquee_caption_content">
          <p>Content goes here</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="marquee_nav">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man! I can't believe that by not adding 1 code word, the slider was giving problem. 

Please explain to me what does the "value" do.

 Index means the numbering, images 0-2, total 3
What does value do? I did not understand about the iteration which you wrote

Comment: Also why didn't '.slide' work? I was targeting the slides, so shouldn't that work?

Comment: @MuhammadAmeenSheikh I will update my answer in a moment with further explanation.